# Babel Compile stops the command chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to run my development server once my lovely Babel compiled my file. But the command chain stops after Babel shows me the success message.

> Successfully compiled 82 files with Babel.

This is my scripts in my `pckage.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
        "clean": "rm -rf dist/*",
        "copy-schemas": "cpx 'src/**/*.{html,png,jpg,graphql}' ./dist",
        "start": "npm-run-all clean compile run-server",
        "compile": "babel --inline --watch src --out-dir dist --extensions '.ts,.tsx,.js'",
        "run-server": "node ./dist/server.js"
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the command you are running to run the server?

Comment: `"run-server": "node ./dist/server.js"` BTW I reckon that's not the problem as if I even put `ECHO '******'` it does not work

Comment: what happens when you run `npm run run-server`

Comment: @nmak18 Just loads the server. But I want it to be in a chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your tasks one at a line, but your `compile` task uses `--watch` which means it will never exit, and thus never give `run-server` the opportunity to run.

If you want to run the CLI watcher alongside a server that restarts, you'd want to use `nodemon` and run that in parallel with the watcher. If you're fine re-running the command whenever you want to test new code, you can remove `--watch` and run with what you have.